# Using a UML diagram to show a project that involves different programming languages

Tags: uml

I'm currently designing the UML diagram for a project that involves the usage of MySQL (for data storing) and Java (for data "presentation"), my question is, is it correct to use a single UML diagram in a project that involves multiple languages? and also, do I need to explicitly show which part "belongs" to each language?
Even though I know UML is a generic representation I had this question because I plan to do all the data processing in the server, and for that I have a class in the package "datos" (data) but for databases I have always used the ER model and also, the class "Reportero" has a bunch of methods that are "symbolic" because their functionality will be achieved with Queries.

[Class in the UML diagram I'm referring to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PDaV.png)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you need to decompose your system into subsystems or components, which you can realize using different languages. The pure UML way is using deployment diagrams, that models the deployment to hardware or to runtime environements like application servers. A less UMLish way is using custom stereotypes at the components that you have defined.

More specifacally, you are asking for a MySQL. In a UML model you model static parts of your system, their properties and interactions based on them. But you usually dont model databases. So what you can do using UML is object oriented analysis, which gives you classes that can represent the entities in your database. But when you say you have class, which operations are realized by queries, you still have something implemented in your language that triggers the execution of the query; in that case I would either define a stereotype used for classes or for operations indicating that the contained operations or the operation has no own logic but just calls the queries.

Further you should get familar with the term model and diagram :-)

Comment: Thank you for such a complete response!

Answer (score 1):

UML is not about diagramming. It is about models - and communicating them to humans by means of diagrams.

What you do in more complex systems is to split them into sub-domains and package them in a meaningful way. In the same way you would create individual diagrams showing static and dynamic system aspects. In your concrete case you could show the database design separate from the runtime design. However, it is also possible to mix both in overview diagrams.